# Bayesian Inference in the presence of multiple hypotheses

Tags: bayesian, inference, multiplicity

> "Because [Bayesian Inference] respects the forward flow of time or information, there's
>   no need for nor availability of methods for correcting for
>   multiplicity ... The evidence of one question
>   is not tilted by whether other questions are being asked."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B-IEMJCtEw

From Frank Harrel's course.

I understand with frequentist inference, the objective is to conserve Type 1 error rate. When we control the family-wise error rate, we consider the family of "questions" being asked and consider a type 1 error for at least one question to be a type 1 error for the family of tests. It also makes sense, therefore, that if we present the 95% CIs for each of the estimands for which the original tests were constructed, we can communicate with a readership about the range of plausible effects that an experiment or data collection process has generated *without* correction.

For a Bayesian, it's easy to see the analogue with estimation and the CI. And we can exonerate ourselves from multiple testing corrections. However, from an inferential standpoint, I don't believe any such claim can be made. But to begin: **What is the Bayesian analogue of a Type 1 error?** The Bayesian upon collecting compelling evidence might be said to "adopt" an updated/alternative probability model for the parameter, if we are to coerce an inferential/decision rule.

The Bayesian might like to control the number of models that are spuriously adopted. In this case, the Bayesian one would need to attenuate the posterior by using an increasingly stringent set of priors depending on the number of tests being used. **Is this the basic approach used and/or is there literature developing these ideas more fully**?

Comment: Here is a paper that addresses this issue rather directly: https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/84/2/419/234015   At the time we wrote it, we did not realize that Jeffreys said something quite similar in his famous book.  Here is a follow-up paper that delves into dependence structures and computation. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1541-0420.00009

Answer (score 1):

Arguments that Bayesians do not need to worry about type I errors are starting from the premise that the type I error rate does not matter/is not a relevant concept* and simply adhere to the likelihood principle**.

I don't think this kind of Bayesian viewpoint is compatible with coercing an inferential threshold, but for taking an action it can work well with decision theory, but then you really need utility functions for how bad it is to be wrong in what way.

* Some Bayesian methods happen to perform well in a frequentist sense, but usually mostly because shrinkage towards plausible parmeter values is usually a good thing.

** If you take your data generating method to be "my main claim is the one that has the highest posterior probability", you can of course argue whether the likelihood principle could be seen to tell you to take that selection into account.

Comment: Agree the decision framework is the unifying paradigm. One thing Bayesians can get that Frequentists can't is an estimate a posterior that incorporates all parameters of interest. So if hypotheses 1 and 2 correspond to probability statements about $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, you can make inferences about $\theta_1$ and subsequently about $\theta_2|\theta_1$ which seems like it could offer some immediate advantages over Bonferroni when done properly.